# Sending Data from ganglia to graphite

Tags: graphite, ganglia

I am currently collecting monitoring metrics with Ganglia and I would like to show graphs with that data with Graphite. I know such an integration is possible, and I found an [article](http://blog.vuksan.com/monitoring/2010/09/29/integrating-graphite-with-ganglia/) describing how it should be done. I am not quite sure exactly how this integration works, especially when I want to send it straight into graphite without parsing the data of the gmetad. Any help on how to integrate Ganglia with Graphite will be great.

thanks

Comment: not yet, the only solution I have is the one in the link I gave which is a script that just copies data from Ganglia to Graphite. What I am looking for, is a solution that sends data directly form Ganglia to graphite, without parsing files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches to integrate ganglia with graphite.

1. use third party process to get metrics from gmetad/gmond, tweak metrics data format, send metrics data to carbon server finally.
2. use the feature "graphite integration" of gmetad where you just need to configure the carbon server address, port, protocol (with an optional graphite path syntax), then gmetad will do all the things left. The more details can be found from your /etc/ganglia/gmetad.conf

I would recommend #2 since it's pretty simple. you just need to upgrade your ganglia packages to version 3.3+.

In above solutions, you can store metrics data in both RRD and whisper. If you don't want this approach, it also supports altering rrdtool graphs with graphite in ganglia-web. see "[Using graphite as graphing engine](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/ganglia-web-2#UsingGraphiteasthegraphingengine)"

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am currently using ganglia 3.6.0 both gmond and gmetad. I have found when setting write_rrds off in the gmetad conf, im loosing a lot of metrics which are being sent to the carbon. Any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: the option [write_rrds](https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/pull/13) is designed to disable storing metrics data into rrd but sending to other store like graphite. I'm not sure what metrics you lost when sending to the carbon cache because it works well in my solution where all default metrics that gmond collected are kept in carbon. One simple method is using command `tcpdump port 2003` on the gmetad host to see what're sent to carbon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the ganglia-web wiki ? There is a section [Graphite Integration](https://github.com/ganglia/ganglia-web/wiki#Graphite_Integration) and an other called [Using Graphite as the graphing engine](https://github.com/ganglia/gangliaweb/wiki#Using_Graphite_as_the_graphing_engine) which explain well how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a lot with Ganglia, Graphite from what I've researched works similarly.  I was never able to master Whisper, but I've found RRD's (round robin databases) to be pretty reliable.  Not sure what you're interested in monitoring, but I would definitely check out JMXtrans.  You can get the code from Google. It provides multiple methods for extracting metric data from whatever JVM you're monitoring, and lets you define which metrics you'd like to pipe to Ganglia/Graphite, and some other options.